# how to add data to a user's profile while not affecting other users' profile React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, components, addition

When a user is clicked, it goes to his/her profile page. Clicking the notes tag on the profile page, user can add notes to his/her profile. But now when any user adds notes, the notes also appear in other users' profile. How to make it so that the added notes only appear on the user's profile who adds the notes?

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import PatientsTable from "./components/PatientsTable";
    import EditPatient from "./components/EditPatient";
    
    function App() {
      const [patients, setPatients] = useState([]);
      const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
      const finalDraftNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.isFinal === true);
    
      const fetchPatients = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users");
        const results = await response.json();
        setPatients(results);
      };
    console.log(notes)
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchPatients();
      }, []);
    
      const handleAddNote = (note) => {
        setNotes((prev) => [note, ...prev]);
      };
    
      const deleteDraftClick = (draftId) => {
        setNotes((prev) => prev.filter((draft) => draft.id !== draftId));
      };
    
      const saveNotesClick = () => {
        setNotes((prev) =>
          prev.map((note) => {
            return {
              ...note,
              isFinal: true,
            };
          })
        );
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <PatientsTable patients={patients} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/patient/:id">
              <EditPatient
                patients={patients}
                notes={notes}
                handleAddNote={handleAddNote}
                deleteDraftClick={deleteDraftClick}
                saveNotesClick={saveNotesClick}
                finalDraftNotes={finalDraftNotes}
              />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import {
      makeStyles,
      Table,
      TableBody,
      TableCell,
      TableContainer,
      TableHead,
      TableRow,
      Paper,
    } from "@material-ui/core";
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      tableContainer: {
        width: 700,
        margin: "20px auto",
      },
      tableHead: {
        backgroundColor: "rgb(25,118,210)",
      },
      tableRow: {
        textDecoration: "none",
      },
    });
    
    export default function PatientsTable({ patients, selectPatientClick }) {
      const styles = useStyles();
      return (
        <TableContainer className={styles.tableContainer} component={Paper}>
          <Table aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead className={styles.tableHead}>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Last name</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">DOB</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Phone Number</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Email</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {patients.map((patient) => (
                <TableRow
                  component={Link}
                  to={`/patient/${patient.id}`}
                  onClick={selectPatientClick}
                  key={patient.id}
                  className={styles.tableRow}
                >
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {patient.fName}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{patient.lName}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{patient.dob}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{patient.pNumber}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{patient.email}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      );
    }
```

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import { formatAMPM, generateId } from "../helper";
    
    import { makeStyles, Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
    import AccountBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountBox";
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      form: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
      },
      textFiled: {
        width: 300,
      },
      btnsContainer: {
        width: 300,
        margin: "20px 0",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
      },
    });
    
    export default function AddNote({ addNote }) {
      const styles = useStyles();
      const { id } = useParams();
      const [note, setNote] = useState(null);
      console.log(id);
      const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
        setNote(target.value);
      };
    
      const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const newNote = {
          userPic: <AccountBoxIcon color="primary" fontSize="large" />,
          user: "Test User",
          time: formatAMPM(new Date()),
          note: note,
          id: generateId(),
          isFinal: false,
        };
    
        if (note) {
          addNote(newNote);
        }
        setNote("");
      };
    
      const handleClearNoteClick = () => {
        setNote("");
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmitClick}>
            <TextField
              className={styles.textFiled}
              label="note"
              multiline
              variant="outlined"
              rowsMax={Infinity}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="add a note"
              value={note}
            />
            <div className={styles.btnsContainer}>
              <Button
                label="add note"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                type="sbumit"
              >
                add note
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={handleClearNoteClick}
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
              >
                clear note
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }
```

```
    import React from "react";
    import { makeStyles, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
    
    export default function Notes({ note, draftIdToDelete }) {
      const styles = useStyles();
    
      const deleteDraftClick = () => {
        draftIdToDelete(note.id);
      };
    
      return (
        <li className={styles.note}>
          <span>{note.userPic}</span>
          <div className={styles.noteDetails}>
            <span>{note.user}</span>
            <span className={styles.time}>{note.time}</span>
            <span>{note.note}</span>
          </div>
          {!note.isFinal ? (
            <Button
              size="small"
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              type="delete"
              className={styles.deleteBtn}
              onClick={deleteDraftClick}
            >
              delete draft
            </Button>
          ) : null}
        </li>
      );
    }
```

```
    import React from "react";
    import AddNote from "./AddNote";
    import Notes from "./Notes";
    import {
      useParams,
      Link,
      Route,
      useRouteMatch,
      Switch,
    } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    import {
      makeStyles,
      Button,
      Typography,
      Card,
      CardContent,
    } from "@material-ui/core";
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      card: {
        width: "70%",
        margin: "auto",
        minHeight: 600,
        position: "relative",
      },
      edit: {
        backgroundColor: "rgb(63,81,181)",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        padding: 16,
        color: "white",
      },
      btnsContainer: {
        margin: "20px 0",
      },
      saveBtn: {
        width: 140,
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 10,
        right: 10,
      },
    });
    
    export default function EditPatient({
      notes,
      handleAddNote,
      deleteDraftClick,
      saveNotesClick,
      finalDraftNotes,
    }) {
      const styles = useStyles();
      const { id } = useParams();
      let match = useRouteMatch();
    
      return (
        <Card className={styles.card}>
          <CardContent>
            <div className={styles.edit}>
              <Typography variant="h5">Edit Patient</Typography>
              <Button color="white" component={Link} to="/">
                X
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.btnsContainer}>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                component={Link}
                to={`${match.url}/details`}
              >
                Detials
              </Button>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                component={Link}
                to={`${match.url}/notes`}
              >
                Notes ({finalDraftNotes.length})
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path={`${match.path}/notes`}>
                <div>
                  <AddNote addNote={handleAddNote} />
                  <ul>
                    {notes && notes.map((note) => (
                      <Notes
                        key={note.id}
                        note={note}
                        draftIdToDelete={deleteDraftClick}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </Route>
              <Route path={`${match.path}/details`}>
                <p>{id}</p>
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </CardContent>
          <Button
            component={Link}
            to="/"
            onClick={saveNotesClick}
            className={styles.saveBtn}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            save & close
          </Button>
        </Card>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What does the `notes` array represent? Each element a note for each patient? CAn patients have multiple notes in the array?

Comment: were you store each profile notes, and where you fetch them

Comment: @DrewReese. When ever a note is created, it looks like this {
      userPic: <AccountBoxIcon color="primary" fontSize="large" />,
      user: "Test User",
      time: formatAMPM(new Date()),
      note: note,
      id: generateId(),
      isFinal: false,
    }; So the notes array contains objects. And yes patients can have multiple arrays. I think the issue now is that the notes array is global for all the patients. I need to find a way to add note for only the targeted patient

Comment: So one note object per patient, or no?

Comment: @DrewReese. The note object should be for the patient whose profile is being edited

Comment: @butalin the notes are stored in local state, no need to fetch them.

Comment: localstate you mean local storage or redux/context api

Comment: Ok, so if 1 patient == 1 note, have you tried filtering the passed notes array for the single matching note element for the current patient being viewed using whatever property associates a note with a patient. I suppose it doesn't matter if it's 1 note per patient though, just filter the `notes` array for *any* matching by id or whatever.

Comment: @butalin useState hook

Comment: @DrewReese No I have not tried that!

Comment: @DrewReese Each patient has an id property. if to implement the logic you mentioned above. how do I do this?

Comment: Probably add a `patientId` field to each note to filter by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very complex code there but I've tried to understand your point of view...finally ohh
Okey, so each patient must have hist own notes, you must first add patient id to each note object, doing this is by getting id params (you already did, and pass it down to AddNote component:

```
export default function EditPatient({//...})
  //.....
const { id } = useParams();
 //.....
<AddNote addNote={handleAddNote} idPatient={id} />
```

Now, move on to your `AddNote` component, we need to add the patient id to note object just like that:

```
export default function AddNote({ addNote, idPatient }) {
/...
const newNote = {
          userPic: <AccountBoxIcon color="primary" fontSize="large" />,
          user: "Test User",
          time: formatAMPM(new Date()),
          note: note,
          id: generateId(),
          isFinal: false,
          idPatient: idPatient //<----add it here
        };
```

Now, what left to do is to filter notes for each patient profile depending on the idPatient, back to EditPatient component:

```
export default function EditPatient({
   //....
const { id } = useParams();
notes = notes.filter((note)=> note.idPatient === id)
```

PS: you are making your code so complex and unreadable, when you are doing a good job, so my advice use state management tools like Context api or redux to make your code cleaner and easy to maintain instead of a top level useState()

Comment: Thanks for your honest comments haha! I did what you suggested. But the idPatient  was mutated. For example, when a note added to patient 1, the idPatient was 1. Then when a note added to patient 2, the idPatient for patient 1 changed to 2.

Comment: can't figure out how it mutated, there is no side effect functions in your code

Comment: Okey i made a mistake in the last piece of code, i should use === to compare instead i used = and always changing idPatient of all notes to the last one hhh ok my bad, i'll edit my answer

Comment: and don't use const because notes already declared

Comment: Oh wow! It works now. And please do not apologize haha! I really appreciate your unconditional help! Except using redux to managing the state. Are there anything else can help my codes look better?

Comment: till now, you are doing so well, good luck, and use Context api, it really makes me happy hhaha